# Passing varying argument to React useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React's docs:

> `const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);`
>
> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

I understand what this says, and that `initialState` is meant to be unchanging. But does anything happen if `initialState` has a different value on subsequent renders? Would it be true to assume that `initialState` is read only once (on first call to `useState`)?

Comment: `initialState` is set only once when component is render's for first time, any subsequent render's don't affect `initialState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `initialState` is passed on and used by useState only once during the initial render and any subsequent change to `initialState` not done by mutation at reference will not update the state value.

However, if you mutate the initialState at its reference it might reflect in the state. However if you make the state update even once before mutating `initialState`, state will not refer to initialState anymore and hence even mutating the `initialState` will not reflect a change in state.